# using c code to find ratio

Tags: c

is it possible to calculate a ratio using a function in C?? or do i have to do up a formula??

Comment: Even your OS is written in C.

Comment: no, you have to use Fortran for formulas.  C is for marine programming.

Answer (score 2):

```
float ratio (float a, float b){
  return a/b;
}
```

You might be having a problem with the following:

```
int a=5;
int b=4;
float ratio=b/a; // yields 1.0000 since it is interpreted as integer division
float ratioCorrect=(float)b/a; // yields 1.25 because yuo told the compiler to interpret numbers as floats
```